# How do I extract a sub-array from a numpy 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to extract a numpy array with a specified size from a numpy 2d array--essentially I want to crop the array.
For example, if have a numpy array like this:

```
([1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9])
```

I'd like to extract a 2x2 from it and the result should be:

```
([1,2],
 [4,5])
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You can use [numpy indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.ndarray.html) array[:2,:2]

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Given this array:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

You can slice it along both dimensions:

```
>>> a[:2,:2]
array([[1, 2],
       [4, 5]])
```